# Vertices of hyperbolic quadrilateral with given angles

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

In a previous post ([link to previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467456/re-vertices-of-hyperbolic-triangle-with-given-angles)), I received help from user dan_fulea on constructing a hyperbolic triangle with given angles. Now, I am attempting to extend this method to quadrilaterals in the Poincaré disk model.

My approach involves reflecting a vertex not on the y-axis across the y-axis in the upper half-plane (UHP) and halving the angles for vertices on the y-axis. However, the computed vertices do not yield the desired angles.

#### Implementation: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=cbsqra

```
import numpy as np

UHP = HyperbolicPlane().UHP()  # UHP is the upper half plane IH
HM = HyperbolicPlane().HM()  # HM  is the hyperboloid model
PD = HyperbolicPlane().PD()

# n1, n2, n3, n4 = 4, 4, 4, 4
n1, n2, n3, n4 = 3, 4, 5, 6
# given angles, we draw a hyperbolic triangle with these angles
# a1, a2, a3, a4 = pi / n1, pi / n2, pi / n3, pi / n4
a1, a2, a3, a4 = pi / n1, pi / n2, pi / n3, pi / n4
# a1, a2, a3, a4 = (2*pi) / n1, (2*pi) / n2, pi / n3, pi / n4
N = 2 * lcm([n1, n2, n3])
F.< u > = CyclotomicField(N)


def c(a1, a2, a3):
    return (cos(a1) + cos(a2) * cos(a3)) / sin(a2) / sin(a3)  # !!! sin(a3) is in denominator !!!


c1, c2, c3 = c(a1, a2, a3), c(a2, a3, a1), c(a3, a1, a2)  # algebraic in the given example


# sides are CC(arccosh(c1)), CC(arccosh(c2)), CC(arccosh(c3))

def toUHP(M):
    """M is a point in the HM model, we construct an ad-hoc version in UHP
    """
    a, b, c = M.coordinates()
    a, b, c = QQbar(a), QQbar(b), QQbar(c)
    return UHP(-(a + i) * (c + 1) / ((b - 1) * c - a ^ 2 - b ^ 2 + b - 1))


def s(v, w):
    """v, w are vectors with three entries, we return the Minkowski product with signature ++-"""
    return v * diagonal_matrix([1, 1, -1]) * w  # no need of a transposition


# a, b, p, q, r are used in the following coordinates in Hyperboloid model
# as a parametrization of points
R.< a, b, p, q, r > = PolynomialRing(F)

V1 = vector([0, 0, 1])
V2 = vector([0, a, b])
V3 = vector([p, q, r])

J = R.ideal([s(V2, V2) + 1, s(V3, V3) + 1,
             s(V1, V2) + c3, s(V2, V3) + c1, s(V3, V1) + c2])
V = J.variety(ring=QQbar)
sols = [sol for sol in V if sol[a] > 0 and sol[q] > 0]  # so V2, V3 maps to IH
sol = sols[0]  # first solution

a0, b0, p0, q0, r0 = [sol[v].real() for v in R.gens()]

S1, S2, S3 = vector([0, 0, 1]), vector([0, a0, b0]), vector([p0, q0, r0])
M1, M2, M3 = HM.get_point(S1), HM.get_point(S2), HM.get_point(S3)
H1, H2, H3 = toUHP(M1), toUHP(M2), toUHP(M3)  # using the ad-hoc coercion from HM to UHP
P1, P2, P3 = PD(H1), PD(H2), PD(H3)
Q1, Q2, Q3 = H1.coordinates(), H2.coordinates(), H3.coordinates()
Q1, Q2, Q3 = CC(Q1), CC(Q2), CC(Q3)
Q4 = CC(-(Q3).conjugate())
pts = [Q1, Q3, Q2, Q4]  # Reorder points to instantiate the polygon to visualise
p1, p2, p3 = P1.coordinates(), P2.coordinates(), P3.coordinates()

l1 = UHP.get_geodesic(Q1, Q2)
l2 = UHP.get_geodesic(Q2, Q3)
l3 = UHP.get_geodesic(Q3, Q4)
l4 = UHP.get_geodesic(Q4, Q1)

_a1, _a2, _a3, _a4 = np.rad2deg(float(l1.angle(l2))), np.rad2deg(float(l2.angle(l3))), np.rad2deg(
    float(l3.angle(l4))), np.rad2deg(float(l4.angle(l1)))
a1, a2, a3, a4 = np.rad2deg(float(a1)), np.rad2deg(float(a2)), np.rad2deg(float(a3)), np.rad2deg(float(a4))
print("Target Angles: ", round(a1, ndigits=2), round(a2, ndigits=2), round(a3, ndigits=2), round(a4, ndigits=2))
print("Angles: ", round(_a1, ndigits=2), round(_a2, ndigits=2), round(_a3, ndigits=2), round(_a4, ndigits=2))
```

I would appreciate any help or corrections to my method. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry but "I would appreciate any insights or corrections to my method" does not qualify as a valid question for MathOverflow.